# Trying to read pdf file stored in res folder android

Tags: android, pdf, runtime-error

Here is code given below..wenever i try to open dat activity it shows the target file doesnt exist..please help me.....thanks in advance

```
public class MainActivityAlgb extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_algb);
            CopyReadAssets();

        }

        private void CopyReadAssets()
        {
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "cure.pdf");
            try
            {
                in = assetManager.open("cure.pdf");
                out = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

                copyFile(in, out);
                in.close();
                in = null;
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                out = null;
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + getFilesDir() + "/cure.pdf"), "application/pdf");

            startActivity(intent);
        }

        private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
            {
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: now where is the file ? res or assets ? because from res you can't. You have to put it in assets folder.

Comment: files are in assets folder

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you have stored the file in res folder.I assume that it is inside raw folder, if not move it to raw folder.Then you can get the file input stream as

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.yourFile);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: if in assets use , AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream is = assetManager.open("yourFile");